# suffix tree: about Ukkonen's algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, string-matching

I have specific question about suffix trees. I am reading the book  [Algorithms on strings_trees and sequence](http://books.google.com/books/about/Algorithms_on_strings_trees_and_sequence.html?id=STGlsyqtjYMC).
I cannot understand details of Ukkonen's algorithm for constructing suffix trees. Why using the skip/count trick, any phase of Ukkonen's algorithm takes O(m) time (theorem 6.1.1)? In particular why over the entire phase, the total number of edge traversals during down-walks is bounded by by 3m?

Comment: I am not sure wether this question has the appropriate level for this site. It would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2), though. So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Comment: @Raphael I committed to CS stack exchange.

Comment: See this answer on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9513423/336563

Comment: and cs.SE is open for business now :)

Comment: wow and the answer over there (stackoverflow) has about 330 upvotes

Comment: It's been 11 hours since Joe's comment; the number of upvotes is now 573.

Comment: Talk about rep-cap.